# aJax update a specific row in sqlite and php using a button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sqlite

I've got a table that lists values inputted by a user, with 2 buttons on the side to remove or to mark completed. On the page the table is visable, there are 3 tabs, we will call these Tab1, Tab2, and Tab3

Each tab has a table (As described above) with information about a specific type of entry.

These buttons are simple `<a href>` links, so when clicked they reload the page. This is a problem because the users view is refreshed and it takes the tabs back to the default tab, and is also an inconvenience when trying to mark several entries.

I would like to make these buttons send Ajax requests to another page to process the data. The only problem is, I am not really sure how to make the ajax call.

This is what I have right now

My buttons

```
            echo "<td class='td-actions'>";
                echo "  <a href='?complete=".$row['uniqueID']."' class='btn btn-success btn-small'>
                            <i class='btn-fa fa-only fa fa-check'> </i>
                        </a> 
                        <a href='?remove=".$row['uniqueID']."' class='btn btn-danger btn-small'>
                            <i class='btn-fa fa-only fa fa-remove'> </i>
                        </a>";
            echo "</td>";
```

There is one called Complete, and one called Remove.

When either of these are pressed, it currently reloads the page which triggers a few php if statements.

```
       if(isSet($_GET['remove'])) {
            $sql = "DELETE from rl_logged where uniqueID='".$_GET['remove']."';";
            $ret = $db->exec($sql);
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;index.php' />";
        }

        if(isSet($_GET['complete'])) {
            $sql = "UPDATE rl_logged set complete=1 where uniqueID='".$_GET['complete']."';";
            $ret = $db->exec($sql);
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;index.php' />";
        }
```

These are relatively simple functions. My problem is that I do not know javascript very well.

Any help would be much appreciated.

the javascript that I have come up with is this

```
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#markComplete').click(function() {
                            var input = input = $(this).text()
                            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                                data: {
                                    onionID: input,
                                },
                                type: 'POST', // GET or POST from the form
                                url: 'pages/ajax/markCompleteRL.php', // the file to call from the form
                                success: function(response) { // on success..
                                   refreshAllTabsWithFade();
                               }
                           });
                        });
                    });
```

using this button

```
                            <div name='markComplete' id='markComplete' class='btn btn-success btn-small'>
                                <i class='btn-fa fa-only fa fa-check'></i>".$row['uniqueID']."
                            </div>
```

But, while inspecting with firebug, this seemed to work ONCE, but now the button doesn't do anything.

[image]

I tried again this morning, the button presses and the first time it sends this post, then the button doesn't do it again - even on page reload.

Comment: What is in your function refreshAllTabsWithFade()?

Comment: @VivekSrivastava I don't really see how that relates, as the function works fine, as it is used elsewhere.

Comment: I asked for the function as there may be case that due to the function some JavaScript error is getting raised an thus your button are disabled for always. Can you please confirm if there are not JavaScript errors on the page?

Comment: @VivekSrivastava There are no javascript errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with the following:

javascript:

```
$('.markComplete').submit( function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), // serialize the form
                type: "POST", // GET or POST from the form
                url: "pages/ajax/repairlogMarks.php", // the file to call from the form
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    refreshAllTabs();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

button:

```
                                 <form class="markComplete">

                                        <input type="text" style="display:none;" class="form-control" name="uniqueid" value='<?=$row['uniqueID'];?>'>
                                        <input type="text" style="display:none;" class="form-control" name="markcomp" value='1'>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                                            <i class="btn-fa fa-only fa fa-check"></i>
                                        </button>

                                </form>
```

Basically, I made the button into a form which I knew how to create an ajax request for.

--
Update to make it work for multiple buttons that do the same function for different unique ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Well for since you're sending the ajax call using "POST", it seems to me that  if(isSet($_GET['complete'])) would evaluate to false. Also if your button is generated dynamically using php then change your click handler to the following:

```
$('document').on('click', '#markComplete', function (){
     // Your code here
 })
```

Comment: The GET I have in the thread is the old way I did it, basically it was just a link that looked like a button that would put a GETTER in the URL. The problem with that is I don't want the page to reload everytime. Your click handler did not work for me, the button is semi-generated dynamically, in the sense that it is created for each table entry with a uniqueid inside of it.

Comment: To prevent the refresh add event.preventDefault() in your button click handler. Also, that handler should work. Did you try console logging something to see if it fires?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one "Mark Complete" button; you need to use classes rather than ID to bind the event.

```
<button id="test">
  Test 1
</button>
<button id="test">
  Test 2
</button>
<script>
$('#test').click(function (e) {
  console.log('test', e.target);
});
</script>
```

In this example, only the first button works.  jQuery will only return the first element when you specify an ID.

If you use classes to bind the event; both buttons will work:

```
<button class="test">
  Test 1
</button>
<button class="test">
  Test 2
</button>
<script>
$('.test').click(function (e) {
  console.log('test', e.target);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you have an error in your javascript at this line...

```
var input = input = $(this).text()
```

try to replace by this..

```
var input = $(this).text();
```

Comment: It seems to be doing the same thing. I got a thing in firebug that showed it posted the data, but now the button doesn't do anything. Attaching an image above.